# Android SurfaceView onDraw halts Thread.join()

Tags: android, multithreading, join, surfaceview, ondraw

I am trying to develop a game with a `SurfaceView`. The thing is that when I whant to destroy the `thread` with the method `surfaceDestroyed()` the application halts in `thread.join()`, but if don't 
draw the canvas (`canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);`) in the `onDraw()` method everything works well. 
How do I do to draw the canvas and call `thread.join()`??

(I tested many example games from the internet and they all have the same problem, when you hit the go back button for example, you get a `FATAL EXCEPTION` because the `thread` is still running)

Here is the code as simple as posible.
Thank you

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        if (gameLoopThread == null) {
            gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            gameLoopThread.start();
            Log.e("thread", "iniciado");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                gameLoopThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        Log.e("thread", "finalizado");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    public static class GameLoopThread extends Thread {
        private static final int FPS = 20;
        private GameView view;
        private boolean running;

        public GameLoopThread(GameViwe gameView) {
            this.view = gameView;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            running = run;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
            long startTime;
            long sleepTime;
            while (running) {
                Canvas c = null;
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try {
                    c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                    synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                        view.onDraw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
                sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                try {
                    if (sleepTime > 0)
                        sleep(sleepTime);
                    else
                        sleep(10);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I gave to this problem is to change where it says:

```
try {
    c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
    synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
        view.onDraw(c);
    }
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
           view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
}
```

on the run() method of the GameLoopThread class with:

```
try {
    c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
    synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
        if(c != null)
            view.onDraw(c);
    }
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
           view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
}
```

To finish this activity and to call another one I added a method called GameOver which works well:

```
private void GameOver() {
    gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
    Context c = getContext();
    c.startActivity(intent); //intent must be declared
    ((Activity) Pruebas.this.getContext()).finish();
}
```

I hope this helps someone.